# Java/JAXB : Adding id to my element without making this appear in the XML file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, attributes

I want to add an `id` to my element, but I don't want this to appear in my XML file. So I tried not to put `@XmlAttribute` nor `@XmlElement`, but it always appears. I just want to set my `id` for my object, to get it back for something else in my program.

Here is my Java code in JAXB (simplified) :

```
public class Equipment {
    private String label;
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

And here it is the result when I create my XML file :

```
<site label="test">
  <equipment id="2" label="test">
  </equipment>
</site>
```

As you can see `id` appears, but it shouldn't.
Thanx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Equipment` class you need to tell JAXB that it should ignore the
`id` property. You do this by annotating it with [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) (instead of with
`@XmlAttribute` or `@XmlElement`).

```
@XmlTransient
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
```

This should result in XML output like this:

```
<site label="test">
  <equipment label="test"/>
</site>
```

Comment: Thanx a lot ! It totally works :D I was looking for Jaxb annotations but I didn't completely understand the meaning (I'm french). But now, that you're explaining, I understand. Thanx :)